# Get the de-selected date from bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to run two different methods when date select and de-select event changes, with enabled `multidate` option.

I could get the correct date on select with 'changeDate' event.

`$(".calendar").on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.date);
});`

But when I de-select the same date, it returns a wrong date for `ev.date`.
(Returns next or previous selected date)

Is there any way to get the correct date when it get de-selected?

Comment: can u please share your code with a js fiddle?

Comment: @MrBearAndBeer , This is the code. http://fiddle.jshell.net/128xorks/

Answer (score 0):

As per the [specs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#cleardate), `clearDate` event is fired only when `clearBtn:true` is enabled and you click on clear button. You can also call

`$('#calendar').val('').datepicker('update');`

to manually trigger the `clearDate` event.

I am able to get the event triggered successfully but unfortunately it is not giving any information about what date was cleared.

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

I have written code to maintain the date deselected by keeping the records of dates selected in `changeDate` event. Here is the fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/128xorks/6/

Comment: Thank you - @Vijay. I've missed that point as well. But I what I need is to get the date which get de-selected. Don't we have an option for that?

Comment: Do you want the de-selection from calender date clicks only?

Comment: Yes. The date which get de-selected.